Gazebo Harmonic slow real time factor on baylands world
I'm attempting to run an Ardupilot-Gazebo simulation using the baylands world downloaded from fuel (https://app.gazebosim.org/VentuRobotics/fuel/models/baylands).
The simulation successfully loads and renders (image below), but the real time factor is extremely slow (~5%). The standard iris_runway world runs at ~90%.
Are there any particular techniques I need to be using to have this run quicker on my machine? I've left my specs below. What's confusing me is that the sim doesn't appear to be using all of my system resources (~40% CPU and memory). Do I have to explicitly set gazebo to use my system's gpu?
I've tried adjusting reducing the <max_step_size> from 250hz to 100hz, but the copter becomes unusable. I've included my base .sdf file below for reference on the plugins being employed.
I'm new to Gazebo simulations so thank you in advance for any support!
System:
CPU: 12th Gen Intel i7-12650H (16) @ 4.600G
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060
GPU: Intel Alder Lake-P GT1
Memory: 32gb DDR4
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS x86_64 (6.8.0-47-generic)
Gazebo Harmonic
ROS2 Humble


baylands.sdf
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version='1.9'>
  <world name='baylands'>
    <physics type="ode">
      <max_step_size>0.004</max_step_size>
      <real_time_factor>1.0</real_time_factor>
      <!-- <real_time_update_rate>250</real_time_update_rate> -->
      <!-- <real_time_update_rate>0</real_time_update_rate> -->
    </physics>

    <plugin name='gz::sim::systems::Physics' filename='gz-sim-physics-system'/>
    <plugin name='gz::sim::systems::Sensors' filename='gz-sim-sensors-system'>
      <render_engine>ogre2</render_engine>
    </plugin>
    <plugin name='gz::sim::systems::UserCommands' filename='gz-sim-user-commands-system'/>
    <plugin name='gz::sim::systems::SceneBroadcaster' filename='gz-sim-scene-broadcaster-system'/>
    <plugin name='gz::sim::systems::AirPressure' filename='gz-sim-air-pressure-system'/>
    <plugin filename="gz-sim-air-speed-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::AirSpeed">
    </plugin>
        <plugin filename="gz-sim-altimeter-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::Altimeter">
    </plugin>
    <plugin name='gz::sim::systems::Imu' filename='gz-sim-imu-system'/>
    <plugin filename="gz-sim-magnetometer-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::Magnetometer">
    </plugin>
    <plugin name='gz::sim::systems::NavSat' filename='gz-sim-navsat-system'/>

    <!-- <plugin name='gz::sim::systems::Contact' filename='gz-sim-contact-system'/> -->
    <!-- <plugin name='gz::sim::systems::ApplyLinkWrench' filename='gz-sim-apply-link-wrench-system'/> -->

    <gui fullscreen='false'>

      <!-- 3D scene -->
      <plugin filename="MinimalScene" name="3D View">
        <gz-gui>
          <title>3D View</title>
          <property type="bool" key="showTitleBar">false</property>
          <property type="string" key="state">docked</property>
        </gz-gui>

        <engine>ogre2</engine>
        <scene>scene</scene>
        <ambient_light>0.4 0.4 0.4</ambient_light>
        <background_color>0.8 0.8 0.8</background_color>
        <camera_pose>-6 0 6 0 0.5 0</camera_pose>
        <camera_clip>
          <near>0.25</near>
          <far>25000</far>
        </camera_clip>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Plugins that add functionality to the scene -->
      <plugin filename="EntityContextMenuPlugin" name="Entity context menu">
        <gz-gui>
          <property key="state" type="string">floating</property>
          <property key="width" type="double">5</property>
          <property key="height" type="double">5</property>
          <property key="showTitleBar" type="bool">false</property>
        </gz-gui>
      </plugin>
      <plugin filename="GzSceneManager" name="Scene Manager">
        <gz-gui>
          <property key="resizable" type="bool">false</property>
          <property key="width" type="double">5</property>
          <property key="height" type="double">5</property>
          <property key="state" type="string">floating</property>
          <property key="showTitleBar" type="bool">false</property>
        </gz-gui>
      </plugin>
      <plugin filename="InteractiveViewControl" name="Interactive view control">
        <gz-gui>
          <property key="resizable" type="bool">false</property>
          <property key="width" type="double">5</property>
          <property key="height" type="double">5</property>
          <property key="state" type="string">floating</property>
          <property key="showTitleBar" type="bool">false</property>
        </gz-gui>
      </plugin>
      <plugin filename="CameraTracking" name="Camera Tracking">
        <gz-gui>
          <property key="resizable" type="bool">false</property>
          <property key="width" type="double">5</property>
          <property key="height" type="double">5</property>
          <property key="state" type="string">floating</property>
          <property key="showTitleBar" type="bool">false</property>
        </gz-gui>
      </plugin>
      <plugin filename="MarkerManager" name="Marker manager">
        <gz-gui>
          <property key="resizable" type="bool">false</property>
          <property key="width" type="double">5</property>
          <property key="height" type="double">5</property>
          <property key="state" type="string">floating</property>
          <property key="showTitleBar" type="bool">false</property>
        </gz-gui>
      </plugin>
      <plugin filename="SelectEntities" name="Select Entities">
        <gz-gui>
          <anchors target="Select entities">
            <line own="right" target="right"/>
            <line own="top" target="top"/>
          </anchors>
          <property key="resizable" type="bool">false</property>
          <property key="width" type="double">5</property>
          <property key="height" type="double">5</property>
          <property key="state" type="string">floating</property>
          <property key="showTitleBar" type="bool">false</property>
        </gz-gui>
      </plugin>
      <plugin filename="VisualizationCapabilities" name="Visualization Capabilities">
        <gz-gui>
          <property key="resizable" type="bool">false</property>
          <property key="width" type="double">5</property>
          <property key="height" type="double">5</property>
          <property key="state" type="string">floating</property>
          <property key="showTitleBar" type="bool">false</property>
        </gz-gui>
      </plugin>
      <plugin filename="Spawn" name="Spawn Entities">
        <gz-gui>
          <anchors target="Select entities">
            <line own="right" target="right"/>
            <line own="top" target="top"/>
          </anchors>
          <property key="resizable" type="bool">false</property>
          <property key="width" type="double">5</property>
          <property key="height" type="double">5</property>
          <property key="state" type="string">floating</property>
          <property key="showTitleBar" type="bool">false</property>
        </gz-gui>
      </plugin>

      <plugin name='World control' filename='WorldControl'>
        <gz-gui>
          <title>World control</title>
          <property type='bool' key='showTitleBar'>0</property>
          <property type='bool' key='resizable'>0</property>
          <property type='double' key='height'>72</property>
          <property type='double' key='width'>121</property>
          <property type='double' key='z'>1</property>
          <property type='string' key='state'>floating</property>
          <anchors target='3D View'>
            <line own='left' target='left'/>
            <line own='bottom' target='bottom'/>
          </anchors>
        </gz-gui>
        <play_pause>1</play_pause>
        <step>1</step>
        <start_paused>1</start_paused>
      </plugin>
      <plugin name='World stats' filename='WorldStats'>
        <gz-gui>
          <title>World stats</title>
          <property type='bool' key='showTitleBar'>0</property>
          <property type='bool' key='resizable'>0</property>
          <property type='double' key='height'>110</property>
          <property type='double' key='width'>290</property>
          <property type='double' key='z'>1</property>
          <property type='string' key='state'>floating</property>
          <anchors target='3D View'>
            <line own='right' target='right'/>
            <line own='bottom' target='bottom'/>
          </anchors>
        </gz-gui>
        <sim_time>1</sim_time>
        <real_time>1</real_time>
        <real_time_factor>1</real_time_factor>
        <iterations>1</iterations>
      </plugin>
      <plugin name='Entity tree' filename='EntityTree'/>
    </gui>
    <gravity>0 0 -9.8</gravity>
    <magnetic_field>6e-06 2.3e-05 -4.2e-05</magnetic_field>
    <atmosphere type='adiabatic'/>
    <scene>
      <ambient>0.8 0.5 1</ambient>
      <grid>false</grid>
      <sky>
        <clouds>true</clouds>
      </sky>
      <shadows>1</shadows>
    </scene>
    <light name='sunUTC' type='directional'>
      <pose>0 0 500 0 -0 0</pose>
      <cast_shadows>false</cast_shadows>
      <intensity>1</intensity>
      <direction>0.001 0.625 -0.78</direction>
      <diffuse>0.904 0.904 0.904 1</diffuse>
      <specular>0.271 0.271 0.271 1</specular>
      <attenuation>
        <range>2000</range>
        <linear>0</linear>
        <constant>1</constant>
        <quadratic>0</quadratic>
      </attenuation>
    </light>
    <include>
      <uri>
        model://baylands
      </uri>
      <name>park</name>
      <pose>205 155 -1 0 0 0</pose>
    </include>

    <include>
      <uri>model://iris_with_gimbal</uri>
      <name>iris</name>
      <pose degrees="true">200 150 0.195 0 0 90</pose>
    </include>
    <spherical_coordinates>
      <surface_model>EARTH_WGS84</surface_model>
      <world_frame_orientation>ENU</world_frame_orientation>
      <latitude_deg>37.412173071650805</latitude_deg>
      <longitude_deg>-121.998878727967</longitude_deg>
      <elevation>38</elevation>
    </spherical_coordinates>
  </world>
</sdf>

